# How to search for all nodes and relationships connected to a specific top node in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-browser

I have started using neo4j and I have several versions of a graph in my neo4j database (the only thing that changes is the timestamp at the top node).

I was wondering how to get only the relations to that one node. I currently use this:

```
"START n=node(*) MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m;"
```

But this just displays all of them. I know I have to change the n=node(*) but I don't know to what. (the name of the top node is: Info) so maybe something like

```
"START n=node(i:Info{timeStamp:'20/04/2018'}) MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m;"
```

but that would just give me the relations to that one node... and I need the whole graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
MATCH (n:Info)-[r]->(m)
WHERE n.timeStamp = '20/04/2018'
RETURN n, r, m;
```

For quicker access to the top node, you should also create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:Info(timeStamp)`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Info(timeStamp);
```

[UPDATED]

To also get all the relationships and nodes to depth 2, you could do this:

```
MATCH (n:Info)-[r1]->(m1)-[r2]->(m2)
WHERE n.timeStamp = '20/04/2018'
RETURN n, r1, m1, r2, m2;
```

To get all the relationships and nodes up to an arbitrary depth (say, 5), you can do this (each returned `path` will be one of the matching paths from `n` to a child node):

```
MATCH path=(n:Info)-[r*..5]->(m)
WHERE n.timeStamp = '20/04/2018'
RETURN path;
```

*You could also just use `[r*]` for an unbounded variable-length search, but that can cause the server to run out of memory or take an extremely long time to finish.*

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you so much! your answer is perfect to get the top node with its relations and connected nodes, but is there any way I can get the nodes and connections of the subnodes?